# MobilePush fails to send push notification

Tags: journeybuilder, android, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

I wanted to send a first test message through MobilePush to my registered device (Android), but the contact's activity dashboard just says "Status: Error" without any further explanation. 
Is there a possibility to get more details on why it failed?

See attached screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the docs for Push Configuration Troubleshooting:

http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

One of the most common problems is customers creating their app in the App Center with the `Android Key` rather than the `Server Key`, but using a REST client like PAW and trying to send directly to the device will help isolate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a misconfiguration in how your device is registering with SFMC. Check the app id, access token and gcm sender id for their accuracy.